# How do I get an unwrapped key in Typesafe Config?

Tags: scala, typesafe, typesafe-config

Test case:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
class HelloWorldSpec extends Specification {
  "Typesafe Config" should "allow me to see my escaped key" in {
    val entries = ConfigFactory.parseString("""
      "quoted.key.1" = 5
      "quoted.key.2" = 6""").entrySet
    entries.head.getKey === "quoted.key.1"
  }
}
```

This test fails because the key is actually `"quoted.key.1"`, not `quoted.key.1`. Is there a suggested way to unwrap this or do I have to manually look for surrounding quotes and remove them every time?

Comment: What about entries.head.getKey === "\"quoted.key.1\""

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio, that is a test case to show the problem. The problem manifests in code. If I don't have a string that needs to be quoted for HOCON, it comes back unquoted in getKey. I don't want to predict the values my administrator will put in there. I was just wondering if there's a way to get keys besides entrySet that may allow me to unwrap them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read about "Paths, keys, and Config vs. ConfigObject" in the API docs here: http://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/Config.html
and in the README here: https://github.com/typesafehub/config#understanding-config-and-configobject

(Suggestions for improving those docs are welcome.)

The keys in the entry set (and the Config) are path expressions. These are strings that require parsing. There is a parse method in ConfigUtil, see http://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/ConfigUtil.html#splitPath%28java.lang.String%29

It won't work to just remove quotes, the parsing is somewhat more complex than that. Fortunately you can just use the `ConfigUtil.splitPath` method.

So the two ways to iterate keys at the root level are something like, first with Config:

```
Config config = ... ;
for (Map.Entry<String, ConfigValue> entry: config.entrySet()) {
  String[] keys = ConfigUtil.splitPath(entry.getKey());
  System.out.println("Root key = " + keys[0]);
}
```

Then with ConfigObject:

```
Config config = ... ;
for (Map.Entry<String, ConfigValue> entry: config.root().entrySet()) {
  System.out.println("Root key = " + entry.getKey());
}
```

I didn't try compiling the above examples so forgive any silly syntax errors.

If your configuration contains only one level (no nested objects) the above two ways of iterating are the same; but if you have nested values they are not the same because iterating `Config` will give you all *leaf* values while iterating `ConfigObject` (`config.root()`) will give you all immediate children of the root, even if those immediate children are themselves objects.

Say you have:

```
foo {
   bar {
       baz = 10
   }
}
```

If you iterate that as a `Config` you will get *one* entry which will have the path `foo.bar.baz` as key and the value `10`. If you iterate it as a `ConfigObject` then you will have one entry which will have the key `foo` and the value will be an object which will in turn contain the key `bar`. When iterating this as a `Config` you could `splitPath` the `foo.bar.baz` and you would get an array of three strings, `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`.

To convert a `Config` to a `ConfigObject` use the `root()` method and to convert `ConfigObject` to `Config` use the `toConfig()` method. So `config.root().toConfig() == config`.

Also, the above config file could be equivalently written as:

```
foo.bar.baz = 10
```

But would be different if written as:

```
"foo.bar.baz" = 10
```

Because in the first case you have nested objects, and in the second case you have a single object with periods in the key name. This is due to the quotes.

If you write `"foo.bar.baz"` with quotes, then when iterating `Config` the path you got back would be quoted and `splitPath()` would return an array of one element `foo.bar.baz`. When iterating `ConfigObject` you would have a single object which would contain an entry with `foo.bar.baz` as key and `10` as value. Keys containing `.`, or other special characters, have to be quoted so they are interpreted as single keys rather than as paths.

To make your test case pass you could do this using splitPath:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
class HelloWorldSpec extends Specification {
  "Typesafe Config" should "allow me to see my escaped key" in {
    val entries = ConfigFactory.parseString("""
      "quoted.key.1" = 5
      "quoted.key.2" = 6""").entrySet
    // the ordering of entrySet is not guaranteed so this may
    // still fail because it gets quoted.key.2 instead
    ConfigUtil.splitPath(entries.head.getKey).head === "quoted.key.1"
  }
}
```

You could also do this, using `ConfigObject`:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
class HelloWorldSpec extends Specification {
  "Typesafe Config" should "allow me to see my escaped key" in {
    val entries = ConfigFactory.parseString("""
      "quoted.key.1" = 5
      "quoted.key.2" = 6""").root.entrySet // note ".root." here
    // the ordering of entrySet is not guaranteed so this may
    // still fail because it gets quoted.key.2 instead
    // no need to splitPath because ConfigObject has keys not paths
    entries.head.getKey === "quoted.key.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: No, splitPath is for something completely different. I don't want the key to be a path, I want the unescaped/unquoted key value. Can you do me a favor and write a quick iteration over either my original config example or the one on https://github.com/typesafehub/config/issues/144 listing all key values?

Comment: The config is a tree, so there is not "a" key vale. For a given setting, you either have one path, or N keys. If N is 1 (your tree is one level deep) then you CAN get a single key. value. There are two ways; iterate ConfigObject (which is just a regular Java Map) or iterate the paths in Config and splitPath each one which should give you a 1-element array. So to get the single key value you splitPath and then do split[0]. I'm on a phone right now so it's pretty hard to write the code out but I would think it is clear how to do it.

Comment: It is not clear. Take `directories { dirone/path = "look I am quoting the value instead of the key", "dir.two's.path.has.a.dot.so.it.is.escaped.in.hocon/path" = someval }`. When you do something like `conf.entrySet.map(e => println(e.getKey + ": " + e.getValue.unwrapped))`, you get `dirone/path: look I am quoting the value instead of the key` and `"dir.two's.path.has.a.dot.so.it.is.escaped.in.hocon/path": someval`. How come I can unwrap a value that had to be quoted, but not a key? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: And I understand they have to be quoted in hocon, I'm asking how to receive a list of unescaped/unquoted keys in Typesafe config.

Comment: Note that I edited the original answer to add a lot more detail and examples. The reason you can't unwrap the key is that it isn't a `ConfigValue`, it's a java.lang.String which contains path expression syntax. There is no "raw"/"unwrapped" key when iterating a Config because you are iterating paths, not keys. To unwrap you have to split the path, creating an array of strings which do not have embedded syntax.

Comment: Maybe I am struggling explaining it. Can you please show me how to get the unquoted key? Remember, this has nothing to do with paths, quotes are there because the key happens to have a dot in it and hocon requires escaping it.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to picture an @ symbol or a comma or something in the key name instead of dots. The point is it has to be quoted if it has those special characters and I am unable to get it back to its pre-quoted value which the user might have meant. If this were pure JSON, and I was iterating in JavaScript, the keys don't keep the quotes around them.

Comment: The answer is the same if it has @ or comma instead of quotes. The way you get the unquoted value is as in the examples in my answer. If you're iterating Config, you splitPath() and then if the path has only one element you take that element. If you're iterating ConfigObject, then you have the key already. The answer DOES have to do with paths, because when iterating Config what you have is a path expression, NOT a key. When iterating ConfigObject, you DO have a key as in JSON already. I will add a fixed version of your test case to the answer.

Comment: Just use ConfigObject instead of Config and it will be just like JSON, that's the short answer perhaps.

Comment: Indeed, that last part made it clear. Sorry I did not grasp Config.entrySet vs ConfigObject.entrySet. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Perhaps this indicates that the distinction between Config and ConfigObject isn't very intuitive

Comment: it obviously isn't but that doesn't mean I know how to improve it (especially given ABI constraints). It is already extensively documented in every place I could think of to mention it.

Comment: Wow, I feel like this should be better documented. This is seriously confusing. I feel like there should be an easy way to get the flattened map of path-value pairs in a `Config`. That's essentially what the author wants, and that's what I'm interested in for something I'm working for, in which the keys are nested purely just for organizational purposes.

Comment: This is documented in a BUNCH of places - the README, and the API docs, and cross-linked from a bunch of places in the API docs, and the API docs (and API) are religious about saying "path" for the path and "key" for the keys. That said, if you looked somewhere where it should have been mentioned but wasn't, please let me know.

To get a flat path-value pairs map, that's what Config is. If you want it as a java.util.Map one approach would be to do config.entrySet() and then iterate the entries adding them to your Map.

Answer (score 0):

in java, first unwarp the whole `ConfigObject` to a hashmap, then you can use `quoted.key.1` (without surrounding quotes) as key to get correct value.