# Play 2.4 HikariCP connection pool configuration

Tags: java, ssl, playframework, typesafe-config

I need to specify some config parameters, separated by dots. Connection pool is in Play 2.4 application. For example

```
db {
  default {
    driver = ${?DB_DRIVER}
    url = ${?DB_URL}
    username = ${?DB_USER}
    password = ${?DB_PASSWORD}
    hikaricp {
      dataSource {
        "javax.net.ssl.trustStore" = ${?DB_TRUST_STORE}
        "javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType" = "JKS"
        "javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword" = ${?DB_TRUST_STORE_PASSWORD}
        "javax.net.ssl.keyStore" = ${?DB_KEY_STORE}
        "javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType" = "JKS"
        "javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword" = ${?DB_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD}
      }
    }
}
```

All parameters like "javax.net.ssl.*" are used to provide details about SSL certificates for connection. Looks like Play framework is trying to parse config keys like "javax.net.ssl.*" and separate them by dots. So it fails with the exception

```
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'javax'
```

I found a similar topic here: [How do I get an unwrapped key in Typesafe Config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738023/how-do-i-get-an-unwrapped-key-in-typesafe-config)
According to the first response

```
foo {
   bar {
       baz = 10
   }
}
```

is the same as

```
foo.bar.baz = 10
```

But it would be different if written as `"foo.bar.baz" = 10`

I hoped that using quotes should help but it doesn't and seems like a bug in the pool configuration implementation. Please, advise.

Answer (score 1):

I answer to complete @brettw answer.

You have to add these parameters as JVM properties when running your play exec :

```
/path/to/bin/<project-name>
  -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/mysql-credentials/keystore \
  -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=YYYYYY \
  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/mysql-credentials/truststore \
  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=XXXXXX \
  ...
```

For those wondering how to create these stores : [read this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html)

I think that `trustStoreType` and `keyStoreType` are not required, I always use JKS types.

Keep in mind that you also have to tell jdbc to use SSL :

```
-Dslick.dbs.default.db.url=jdbc:mysql://DOMAIN_OR_IP/DATABASE?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true
```

Last but not least you can debug the handshakes with :

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

It gives you a lot (MB) of informations on handshakes, renegociation and ciphers printed on stdout

Answer (score 0):

These are typically JVM properties, do I don't know if it is appropriate to put them in the db/dataSource configuration.   Even if it is the driver that uses these, those are system-wide properties and would apply to all SSL components.